# .net Core - NLog package

Tags: nuget, nlog, .net-core

I have a .NET project that uses the NLog nuget package. I want to port this to .NET Core - but NLog can not be used with .NET Core.

NLog is partly based on the System.Configuration namespace - what seems not to be implemented in the .NET Core Framework.

So are there alternative logging libraries on nuget I can use with are supporting .NET Core?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.Net Core is expected in NLog 4.4. It is in beta state now but you can try it. You can find nuget package [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog).

I have seen using Serilog successfully in [this project](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/dev/src/Host/project.json#L16) so you can try it too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but then i find out the stable version of NLog that is

> "NLog": "4.3.5"

You can add the above mentioned reference in your projet.json file in dependencies area.

```
> {
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "Business Class Library",
  "authors": [ "Salman.tariq.lone" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Data": "1.0.0-*",
        "NLog": "4.3.5",
        "HtmlAgilityPack": "1.4.9",
        "RestSharp": "105.2.3",
        "Unofficial.Ionic.Zip": "1.9.1.8"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "LibGit2Sharp": "1.0.0-*"
  },
  "compilationOptions": {
    "allowUnsafe": true
  }
}
```

The above section is my project.json file where you can see the NLog reference. It is working in my case.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I decided to use "NLog" with version "4.4.0-betaV15" (so a beta version, but thats fine for me. My RTM date will be after the 4.4.0 RTM date ...)

Comment: @leo90skk Pleasure. kindly vote my answer if it was useful.